# ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::mail() does not exist

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.3

Route details:-

```
Route::get('/email_id_exist','Auth\LoginController@mail');
```

Controller details

```
    <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
    use App\Models\UserAdmin;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
public function mail(Request $request)
    {
    ....Some code here... and returned back;
    }
    }
```

Controller path:-

```
....project_name\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php
```

Error is only shown on server which is linux based (Error displaying:), and on my windows local it is working properly.
Php version for server is 7.0.7 and on my local is 7.0.9 
 Please help

Comment: if it works on your local maybe its php version issue can you write namespace line in second ?
`<?php  ENTER 
namespace`

Comment: The namespace is on the second line. But still throw the error,I also gave the file permission to 777 to check if that was the problem but the same error still exist and php version is 7.0.7

Comment: try this to post  Route::post('/email_id_exist','Auth\LoginController@mail');

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
      It was all because `(ModelName::where('v_id',1)->count();)` which was causing an error just added a space between **'v_id', 1**   so `(ModelName::where('v_id', 1)->count();)` and it was solved. This worked for me, Thanks everyone for helping Cheers njy.